# Show Related Terms Block Not Nodes

Tags: 6, views

Hello i have been trying for many a moon to create this View and i cant go on any longer its destrying my life (honest)

I want to show Related Terms (not content) on my taxonomy/term/* page. Example.

White Setter and Black Setter are both in a dogs vocabulary. I have 'related' them via the 
taxonomy/term/***/edit-term page.

I want to create a block view that will show Black Setter on the White Setter page and vica versa. I have tried every relationship and every argument with no success at all. Does anyone know if this is possible to make?

Relationships
Taxonomy: Related terms
Arguments
Taxonomy: Term ID

Thanks

Before i post i see that i have asked ths on other peoples posts (and one of mine) they where never resolved. People keep talking about adding nodes in the view but i was wanting to use a term View.

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using ? 6 or 7 ?

Comment: Sorry Anil Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really hard:

1. Create a new taxonomy view.
2. Add an argument: `Taxonomy: Term ID`. If argument is not present, provide a default argument: `Taxonomy Term ID from URL`. Check the `Load default argument from term page` checkbox.
3. Add a relationship: `Taxonomy: Related terms`.
4. Finally, add a field: `Taxonomy: Term`. Use the `Related term` relationship, and check the `Link this field to its taxonomy term page` option.
5. Don't forget to create the block display.

Here's a view export: https://gist.github.com/4016927

Comment: Core stores term relationships as "A is related to B" and the Views handler is not wise enought to check that "B is related to A". Therefore, right now, this is broken in Views 6.x-2.x and 6.x-3.x (didn't check 7.x-3.x).

Comment: See http://drupal.org/node/1825688

Comment: thanks barraponto i missed this. yes that was me on drupal.org. i will go look more at this as the view will interest me. Loads to get on with now this is solved but i will return

Comment: barraponto's View does seem to work ok and as i had hoped (including on the node) I need to edit each term and resave them for the 2 way relationship to come into place. Sorry folks im just up and not thinking straight. Sorry Anoop but using a view like barra suggested seems a better way for me to go. thanks for your input though

Comment: @RegGordon unfortunately, saving the related term will break it on the other related term. So right now, what you're left with is custom code.

Comment: @Reg Gordon Are you able to get related terms using this way? Well when i tried am able to show relation one way only, two way not possible.

Answer (score 5):

As your requirement is to create a block that will show Black Setter on the White Setter page and vica versa, there is another simple way to achieve this.  The function [taxonomy_get_related()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_related/6) will do this.

Create a block with input format as php and use above function to print related terms by passing current page term id. Then assign the block to particular region. The following snippet will works,

for eg:

```
 <?php
    $termid = arg(2);
    $terms = taxonomy_get_related($termid, $key = 'tid');
    //print_r($terms);
    foreach($terms as $term){

       $link = url('taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid);
       echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: ah brilliant Anoop that seems to be the way to go. It is printing the term fine as hoped but it isnt linking the term to the term page. Would there be a way to sort this? thanks very much.

Comment: i edited answer please check now

Comment: lovely works a dream Anoop. Much appreciated. This really helps me and im sure it will realy help others too.

Comment: is there any way that the output could also be displayed on a node to emulate the " Load default argument from node page, thats good for related taxonomy blocks" way? I was hoping to use this as a menu system. thanks

Comment: As I explained in my answer's comments, Views handling of related terms is broken, so you're left with custom code solutions. That said, avoid leaving snippets of PHP in your database as debugging or mantaining it is way harder than actual code.

Comment: You're better of with a custom block (using `hook_block()`) that checks the current url (`using arg()`) and builds the related term links (using `taxonomy_get_related()` and `theme_links()`).